# Chromium crashes as soon as I log in

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, chromium, crash

Just today, without me doing any special kind of update or plugin that I am aware of, the Chromium browser closes instantly after startup. When trying to start it in the terminal, I get this message:

```
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000010
#0 0x7ff2a0573425 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7ff2a057380b <unknown>
#2 0x7ff2a089e390 <unknown>
#3 0x56177f66adc8 <unknown>
#4 0x56177f66d656 <unknown>
#5 0x56177f66ddf9 <unknown>
#6 0x56177f66e143 <unknown>
#7 0x7ff2a05ee821 <unknown>
#8 0x7ff2a0574eea base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask()
#9 0x7ff2a059de90 base::MessageLoop::RunTask()
#10 0x7ff2a059f97d base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask()
#11 0x7ff2a05a083d <unknown>
#12 0x7ff2a05a1300 base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run()
#13 0x7ff2a059cf15 base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()
#14 0x7ff2a05c7628 base::RunLoop::Run()
#15 0x7ff2a05f3e36 base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#16 0x7ff2a05ee726 <unknown>
#17 0x7ff2a08946ba start_thread
#18 0x7ff289f433dd clone
r8: 000000000000002e  r9: 00005617810c16ec r10: 0000000000000000 r11: 00007ff289fd0f50
r12: 00007ff1f17f6ff0 r13: 0000000000000008 r14: 0000000000000008 r15: 00007ff1f17f6eb0
di: 0000000000000000  si: 00007ff1f17f6eb0  bp: 00007ff1f17f6f00  bx: 00007ff1f17f6eb0
dx: 000000000000005e  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 0000561782b3af60  sp: 00007ff1f17f6e60
ip: 000056177f66adc8 efl: 0000000000010206 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000010
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

It changes slightly each time I try, but it always comes out basically that way, and I have no idea what it is saying.

Tried uninstalling chromium-browser and reinstalling. No change.

So I deleted ~/.config/chromium and re-ran, and the browser didn't crash. Yay! but then I logged into Google, and crashed with the same message shown above. So I started it up again, and didn't log in. So far so good. But as soon as any complicated website is opened, it crashes within a few seconds.

So then I opened Firefox. Since I'm writing this on the browser, it finally seems stable. So I can log into Google on Firefox with no trouble, then why is Chromium crashing on it?

Using Ubuntu 16.04. I've searched around for answers, and there are lots of people who experienced similar problems several years ago, but obviously that's irrelevant now as many versions have changed since.

For the record, I've also tried is to run `chromium-browser --password-store=basic` with no change. I've also tried downloading the repository using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage`, update, and re-install. No change. Also tried running `chromium-browser --disable-gpu`. No change.

I would really appreciate an answer as soon as possible, as I am very frustrated having to deal with this.

Comment: In Mint, Chrome does work while Chromium has the same issue:
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Comment: In my defense, that question had no answer when I posted this

Comment: My duplicate flag is not meant as a criticism. Just trying to keep things together that belong together. :-)

Comment: It's the cast extension. See my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/932353/653294).

Comment: Seems to be the cast extension. See https://askubuntu.com/a/932353/653294.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint this morning with 59.0.3071.109 -- `SEGV_MAPERR` crashes. I ran `chromium-browser --disable-extensions`. Then disabled hardware acceleration. Previously I had it disabled because GPU processes leaks memory. But it seems it was re-enabled on upgrade. After that the old version worked normally.

## Update

Downgraded to 58.0.3029.96 from `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Even though I disabled hardware acceleration GPU process is still around, and I have glitches in extension rendering.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is about some extension inside the browser.
Launching with command `chromium-browser --disable-extensions` works well for me.

Navigate to chrome://flags and search for "media router" and set it to Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment.

I just wanted to add that there is a bug report for this issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1702407

There are now fixed packages available from the above bug report.