# Permanently re-enable Chromium extensions in 16.04

Tags: launcher, chromium

A day ago I disabled Chromium extensions via `chromium-browser --disable-extensions`, as advised in many answers [to this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932016/chromium-crashes-as-soon-as-i-log-in).

After that I successfully re-enabled them with `chromium-browser --enable-extensions`, which opens Chromium from the terminal.

However, whenever I start Chromium from Unity Launcher now, it opens with extensions disabled. Could anyone explain to me how I can re-enable them permanently for sessions initiated from the Launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: When dealing with the current Chromium problem mentioned above, I must have accidentally created a file `~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`. Whether Chromium was installed or not, Unity would point to that file only. I presume said desktop file must have stored the info to disable extensions. Deleting it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`--disable-extensions` should only apply to the session you launched with that parameter.  It does not change settings.  Are you sure you did not do anything else, like delete/rename your session directory as well?

See my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/932353/653294) for a work around and test packages for the original crash issue.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer: After purging Chromium, when searching for "Chromium" in dash, an entry was still found, however labelled "Signal Private Messenger - Chrome Web Store - Chromium", but with the standard Chromium icon. Even when the 'proper' Chromium is installed, Unity still points at that weird entry. Do you happen to know how I can tell Unity to point at the proper Chromium?

Comment: Thanks again for the hint in the first paragraph; that clarified that Chromium itself was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would find the .desktop file and enable the Exec command to include the desired setting --enable-extensions that way the setting is parsed even when you launch it from unity or gnome.

Comment: Thanks, but this smells a bit like a workaround, doesn't it? I mean, Chromium used to launch with extensions by default, without me having meddled with the (so far entirely empty) .desktop file before.