# Chromium brower won't stay open

Tags: chromium

Everything the browers opens up in ubuntu 16.04. It immediately shutdown. I have tried opening it in terminal. I have received the following message.

```
** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Couldn't create item: The secret was transferred or encrypted in an invalid way.
** Message: received an invalid or unencryptable secret
** Message: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Couldn't create item: The secret was transferred or encrypted in an invalid way.
[19314:19366:0705/211845.216595:ERROR:gcm_store_impl.cc(929)] Failed to restore security token.
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000010
#0 0x7ff0f6a50425 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7ff0f6a5080b <unknown>
#2 0x7ff0f6d7b390 <unknown>
#3 0x56058501fdc8 <unknown>
#4 0x560585022656 <unknown>
#5 0x560585022df9 <unknown>
#6 0x560585023143 <unknown>
#7 0x7ff0f6acb821 <unknown>
#8 0x7ff0f6a51eea base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask()
#9 0x7ff0f6a7ae90 base::MessageLoop::RunTask()
#10 0x7ff0f6a7c97d base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask()
#11 0x7ff0f6a7d83d <unknown>
#12 0x7ff0f6a7e300 base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run()
#13 0x7ff0f6a79f15 base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()
#14 0x7ff0f6aa4628 base::RunLoop::Run()
#15 0x7ff0f6ad0e36 base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#16 0x7ff0f6acb726 <unknown>
#17 0x7ff0f6d716ba start_thread
#18 0x7ff0e04173dd clone
  r8: 00007ff07471ed00  r9: 0000560586a766ec r10: 0000000000000000 r11: 00007ff0e04a4f50
 r12: 00007ff07471eff0 r13: 0000000000000008 r14: 0000000000000008 r15: 00007ff07471eeb0
  di: 0000000000000000  si: 00007ff07471eeb0  bp: 00007ff07471ef00  bx: 00007ff07471eeb0
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007ff0c4009570  sp: 00007ff07471ee60
  ip: 000056058501fdc8 efl: 0000000000010206 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000010
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

Comment: Try uninstalling it and reinstalling it via Ubuntu SOftware

Comment: tried that, didn't work.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/931978/chromium-immediate-shutdown-upon-launch-ubuntu-16-04/932353

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove all the extensions on it?

Launching it with `--disable-extensions` could help.

Also, try to check here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: That seems to have work, although I will try to figure out which extension cause the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @JuanPineda If this worked,. you should upvote it and click the tick to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm happy this solved your problem mate ;) @JuanPineda