# Chromium wont start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

```
I'm having this problem:

$ chromium-browser
[15020:15020:0706/102351.636730:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(13)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000010
#0 0x7f9d03a41425 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7f9d03a4180b <unknown>
#2 0x7f9d03d6c390 <unknown>
#3 0x557bae6e3dc8 <unknown>
#4 0x557bae6e6656 <unknown>
#5 0x557bae6e6df9 <unknown>
#6 0x557bae6e7143 <unknown>
#7 0x7f9d03abc821 <unknown>
#8 0x7f9d03a42eea base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask()
#9 0x7f9d03a6be90 base::MessageLoop::RunTask()
#10 0x7f9d03a6d97d base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask()
#11 0x7f9d03a6e83d <unknown>
#12 0x7f9d03a6f300 base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run()
#13 0x7f9d03a6af15 base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()
#14 0x7f9d03a95628 base::RunLoop::Run()
#15 0x7f9d03ac1e36 base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#16 0x7f9d03abc726 <unknown>
#17 0x7f9d03d626ba start_thread
#18 0x7f9ced4113dd clone
  r8: 000000000000002e  r9: 0000557bb013a6ec r10: 0000000000000000 r11: 00007f9ced49ef50
 r12: 00007f9c537faff0 r13: 0000000000000008 r14: 0000000000000008 r15: 00007f9c537faeb0
  di: 0000000000000000  si: 00007f9c537faeb0  bp: 00007f9c537faf00  bx: 00007f9c537faeb0
  dx: 0000000000000069  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007f9c34008aa0  sp: 00007f9c537fae60
  ip: 0000557bae6e3dc8 efl: 0000000000010206 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000010
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

The issue started this morning after the /boot partition was reported full. I cleaned it, but the issue remains. 
At this point, I could not find any other question that contains the same stack trace or that is related to this particular issue.

I have tried several things I found on the web, all resulting in the same error, again and again:

Tried moving the cache somewhere else:

```
 mv ~/.cache/chromium oldshit
```

Tried deleting the cache:

```
 rm ~/.config/google-chrome/*
 cd ~/.cache/chromium 
 rm -rf *
```

Tried un-installing and install again:

```
 sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
 sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/931978/chromium-immediate-shutdown-upon-launch-ubuntu-16-04/932353

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromium immediate shutdown upon launch Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931978/chromium-immediate-shutdown-upon-launch-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been caused by the recent update to version 59.0.3071.109.

The temporary solution is to try to open it without extensions:

```
chromium-browser --disable-extensions
```