# Chromium won't start on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS Raspberry Pi

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, mate, raspberrypi

When I try to run Chromium(`chromium-browser`), it displays only the title bar and a border. Here's the error log:

```
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
Received signal 4 <unknown> 000076283f76
#0 0x000076ed7d12 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x000076ed7952 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x000076ed7ffc <unknown>
#3 0x0000722cd270 <unknown>
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
Received signal 4 <unknown> 000076283f76
#0 0x000076ed7d12 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x000076ed7952 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x000076ed7ffc <unknown>
#3 0x0000722cd270 <unknown>
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
Received signal 4 <unknown> 000076283f76
#0 0x000076ed7d12 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x000076ed7952 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x000076ed7ffc <unknown>
#3 0x0000722cd270 <unknown>
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
[3728:3728:0714/230011.042444:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(343)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process. 
[3651:3681:0714/230011.074254:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[3651:3681:0714/230011.075020:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[3651:3681:0714/230011.075433:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[3651:3681:0714/230011.075699:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[3651:3681:0714/230011.075936:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)]     Failed to launch GPU process.
Received signal 4 <unknown> 00007622ff76
#0 0x000076e83d12 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x000076e83952 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x000076e83ffc <unknown>
#3 0x000072279270 <unknown>
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

How can I get this to work?

NOTE: I've had a similar problem with Xubuntu as well, but it works fine on Raspbian.

From looking [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932625/chromium-wont-start-on-ubuntu-16-04), I think that it might be problem from a new update, becuase updating chromium caused it to happen in the first place.

If this is true, Could you please tell me how to downgrade (Opposite of upgrade) to a version below 59?

Comment: Raspbian isn't Ubuntu.  Nor is it really even Debian.  Just making that known.

Comment: @ThomasWard What do you mean Raspbian isn't really Debian. Isn't it just a distro of Debian, like Ubuntu?

Comment: Raspbian is the RPI foundation's *fork* of Debian with a lot of other changes that make it differ from Debian enough to be considered "not debian".  It may pull from Debian's repos but they have a lot of additional packages and repositories that add special things.  Raspbian is offtopic here though.

Comment: Why did you suicide?

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about it being a version problem, I decided to look around and found this website: http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/, the official website for the chromium found in APT repositories.

So I looked around, tried out a few versions, and finally, managed to get chromium working by installing

```
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu1.1348_armhf.deb
chromium-browser_57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu1.1348_all.deb
chromium-browser-l10n_57.0.2987.98-0ubuntu1.1348_all.deb
```

In that order. See [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) if unsure; you can, for example, `cd` to the download directory and run

```
sudo apt-get install ./<name of package>.deb
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that an "official website", it's more of the actual contents of the repo. :) Good answer BTW! You may also consider pinning that package (if I recall the verb correctly) so that it doesn't upgrade again to the broken version.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I couldn't find a better word and will change it. Also how do I pin the repo?

Comment: You answered your own question then suicided

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to get Chromium to work on Ubuntu Mate. It wouldn't start. I took my time reading through forums trying to find out what's wrong. 15 minutes into it, it suddenly opened up on my raspberry pi's screen by itself (I guess the process was still running). After that it worked normally. I'm still not sure what it was doing there for 15 minutes