# Chromium browser doesn't open on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, chromium

Chromium browser doesn't open in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried to open Chromium browser via command line interface, namely terminal, by writing `chromium-browser`, but it doesn't open. CLI shows the following message:

```
Using PPAPI flash.
 --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=
Created new window in existing browser session.
[16942:16982:0801/021450.373005:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` command on CLI:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5902 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 5902
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Looks like a graphics problem. What is your graphics hardware and used driver? Can you include the output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` please?

Comment: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5902 (rev 04)
 Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 5902
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915`       @ByteCommander

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/932625/367990 or https://askubuntu.com/q/936072/367990 ? I'd especially try the start without extensions answer first.

Comment: I tried `chromium-browser --disable-extensions` on CLI and this shows, browser doesn't still open: `Using PPAPI flash.
 --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=
Created new window in existing browser session.
[22403:22443:0801/025306.892625:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.` @ByteCommander

Comment: No more ideas then... Maybe you can do some further online research about that error message yourself, but I haven't really found anything useful. Sorry.

Comment: Tried using `--disable-gpu` flag?

Comment: @robobenklein Thanks, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned the problem was with display. I learned it through screenshot I took. It showed double screens. So I looked on the internet for the answer and learned that I had to turn off the "Built-in Display" in System Settings -> Displays menu. After turning off that "Built-in Display" in System Settings, all browsers that was not opening before started to open. Google Chrome, Chromium browser and Opera browser are working now. Vivaldi browser was not showing an extra new window, but that is also working now.