# Chromium problems on xubuntu

Tags: chromium

I had been running Chromium under xubuntu with no problems whatsoever. Now, when I try to start Chromium, I get the "Restore Pages? Chromium did not shut down correctly" box. No matter what I do from this point, Chromium just shuts down. Any ideas?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/931978/chromium-immediate-shutdown-upon-launch-ubuntu-16-04/932353